# Nginx does not serve page when accessed from localhost

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, webserver

My nginx configuration does not serve any page when it is accessed from localhost. For example: When I access the site externaly via it's url (let's say example.com) it happily serves the page. When I run 'curl localhost' from the server that is running nginx itself, it responds with 404 Not Found.

This is the nginx site config:

```
server {
    listen *:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_error.log;

    # Main application:
    location / {
        root /var/www/example.com/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

(please note that i replaced my url with 'example.com' for privacy reasons)

The site currently only contains a hello world text, that is happily served when running 'curl example.com':

```
example@example.com:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ curl example.com
Hello World!!!
```

But when I run 'curl localhost' i only get:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Try replacing `servername localhost;` with `servername _;`

Comment: Changing to ```servername _;``` did not solve it.

Comment: Does `curl http://localhost/` (with slash at the end) work?

Comment: Nope. Still "404 not found".